# Logrotate docker container's logs when user doesn't exist on host

Tags: linux, docker, logging, logrotate, log-rotation

I mounted my containers' logs to the host (e.g. `/var/log/container1`, etc). Now I want to use the host's `logrotate`.

But suppose I need to do this:

```
create 660 mysql mysql
```

There is no `mysql` user/group on the host, so logrotate fails with:

> unknown user 'mysql'

So I tried:

```
create 660 999 999   # 999 is mysql user's uid/gid within container
```

But then I get:

> unknown user '999'

So I tried:

```
create 660 999 999
su 999 999
```

But that gives the same error.

How can I do this, *without* creating a dummy user on the host?

(BTW, before you tell me to rely on docker's own log rotation... this is just an example. I use various containers which do not log to stdout/stderr so I need to do log rotation myself.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is `logrotate` does not recognise a non-existent uid/gid, even though the filesystem does.

Workaround:

```
#create 660 mysql mysql                # break it: will use default of root:root
postrotate
  chown 999:999 /var/log/container1/   # fix it
endscript
```

This could lead to a race condition though.

If you have a better solution, please post it.